# how to change header name appear in forest plot in R?

Tags: r

[image: its my dataset. event= Sal_pos, N= Total_sample]
I want to change the word event and replace it with prevalence. How to do it?
I have used the package 'meta' and 'metasens'. my commands were,

```r
res= metaprop( event= Sal_pos, n= Total_sample, studlab=paste(Author, Year), comb.fixed= TRUE, comb.random= TRUE, method.tau= 'ML', pscale= 100, data=..)
forest(res, sortvar= Year, prediction= TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Himel. Welcome to Stack Overflow. We don't know which of the several packages that you could use to generate a forest plot you have used here. We don't know what code you used to generate the plot. We don't know what your variables are called. We don't have your data. All we have is the (top half of) your picture. You really need to provide more information than this when asking a question here, otherwise no-one will be able to answer.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I have updated my question. Please have a look, Allan.